# VB.net JSON Deserialize

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I've got the following JSON string to deserialize:

`[{"application_id":"1","application_package":"abc"},{"application_id":"2","application_package":"xyz"}]`

I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer method.

It is made up of array of items and I couldn't find an example using VB.Net that can deserialize this structure. I have the following Application class to store this information:

```
    <DataContract(Namespace:="")> _
    Public Class ApplicationItem

    <DataMember(Name:="application_id")>
    Public Property application_id As String

    <DataMember(Name:="application_package")>
    Public Property application_package As String

    End Class
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use `JavaScriptSerializer` over `DataContractJsonSerializer`. The reasons are:

- `JavaScriptSerializer` is faster over `DataContractJsonSerializer`
- `DataContractJsonSerializer` requires more code than `JavaScriptSerializer` for a simple serialization.

You won't need the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attribute to use along with `JavaScriptSerializer`

Use this data class

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class ApplicationItem
    Public Property application_id() As String
        Get
            Return m_application_id
        End Get
        Set
            m_application_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_application_id As String
    Public Property application_package() As String
        Get
            Return m_application_package
        End Get
        Set
            m_application_package = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_application_package As String
End Class
```

And use this to deserialize your `jsonText`:

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of ApplicationItem))(jsonText)
```

If you still want to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`, you can use this code below to deserialize:

```
Dim obj As New List(Of ApplicationItem)()
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json))
Dim serializer As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.[GetType]())
obj = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(ms), List(Of ApplicationItem))
ms.Close()
ms.Dispose()
```

Courtesy: Used [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you for showing a link to a code converter too.

Comment: I am not familiar with VB.NET syntax and use it often to convert C# code to VB.NET :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the hint! It is really easier to use JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: If JavaScriptSerializer is faster thant DataContractJsonSerializer, why does json.net advertise itself as being "50% faster than DataContractJsonSerializer, and 250% faster than JavaScriptSerializer" on their [website](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: @mijiturka Even though JSON.NET had acceptable ground back in those days but probably not as much as of today. If I've answered this question today, I'd have used JSON.NET :)

Comment: Didn't see the date - was wondering which of the built-ins is faster but that must have changed in 7 years!

Answer (score 30):

Here is the easiest way to deserialize JSON into an object (using .NET 4):

Example JSON:

```json
{
    "dogs":[],
    "chickens":[
        {
            "name":"Macey",
            "eggs":7
        }, 
        {
            "name":"Alfred",
            "eggs":2
        }
    ]
}
```

VB.NET:

```vb
Try
    Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(JSONString)
    Dim a = j("dogs")                   ' returns empty Object() array
    Dim b = j("chickens")(0)            ' returns Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim c = j("chickens")(0)("name")    ' returns String "Macey"
    Dim d = j("chickens")(1)("eggs")    ' returns Integer 2
Catch ex As Exception
    ' in case the structure of the object is not what we expected.
End Try
```

Comment: While Abdul's answer is more complete, this is indeed the easiest way to access JSON data in a quick and dirty way (such as a small, predictable set from an API response).

Comment: Wow this really helped me out, I was looking for something fast and simple and you did it !!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
// Get the HttpWebRequest reaponse
string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(Response);
string carrier = (dict["Response"]["carrier"]);
```