# How to loop in client side object Array in visual Basic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, json, object

I created a JSON object in the client side And then Pass it into a `asp:HiddenField`

Here is a part Of that `Object`

```
"[{"value":"0","column":"lngTask"},{"value":"End Checklist","column":"strTask"},
  {"value":"0","column":"lngChecklistRevision"},
  {"value":"","column":"lngManagedTask"}......]"
```

Then I wanted to Use it in my code behind I'm Using `Visual Basic`

So i used `JavaScriptSerializer()` Like this :

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim lstReport As List(Of Object) = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))
    (hfObjSqlGridRow.Value)
```

Here is how my `lstReport` Looks like :

[image]

*My Question* Is how can i loop through this object

i have tried things like :

```
lsReport(0)(0)
lsReport(0).(0).value
lsReport(0).value
```

Nothing works i get this Error = **The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is in C#, but should be easy enough to convert to VB.NET. The basic premise is to use a dynamic JSON serializer that allows accessing properties at run-time like a JSON object in JavaScript. You must be using .NET 4.0 for dynamic object support.

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: The same should apply in VB setting option strict off.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use the `For Each` loop?

```vb
For Each item In lsReport
    ' Do whatever you need with item.value
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim JSObject as String =
[
  {"00ID": "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_000_ParentCatTxt", "00Val": "Page"}, 
  {"00ID": "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_001_CatTxt", "00Val": "Inherite Parent"}, 
  {"00ID": "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_002_SubCatTxt", "00Val": "Inherite Parent"}, 
  {"00ID": "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_010_UCI", "00UCItype" : "UCItf", "00Val": "false", "01Txt": "Include related containers", "02Tip": "include related containers"}
]

            Dim serializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim obj As Object = serializer.Deserialize(Of Object)(JSObject)

    s = GetProp(obj, "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_000_ParentCatTxt.00Val")
            SetProp(obj, "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_000_ParentCatTxt.00Val", "NEwVal")
            s = GetProp(obj, "PTDA_000ParentCat_000Cat_000SubCat_000_ParentCatTxt.00Val")
            s = ""

Public Function GetProp(objf As Object, propPath As String) As String
    Dim propVal As String = ""
    Dim propPathAr As Array = Split(propPath, ".")
    'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize
    For Each item In objf
        If item("00ID") = propPathAr(0) Then
            propVal = item(propPathAr(1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return propVal
End Function
Public Sub SetProp(ByRef objf As Object, propPath As String, val As String)
    Dim propPathAr As Array = Split(propPath, ".")
    For Each item In objf
        If item("00ID") = propPathAr(0) Then
            item(propPathAr(1)) = val
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation and edit the code, it's totally messed up.