# JSON.net getting value in child while looping

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

Hey all I am trying to get the values in **F_TableOtherFamily->F_Table** and loop to get the name and values of whats inside that but I can not seem to do that with using the following code:

```
For Each msg As JObject In json1("entry")
   Dim results As List(Of JToken) = msg("content")(formName).ToList()

   For Each pair As JProperty In results
      pair.CreateReader()

      If pair.Descendants.Count > 1 Then
         'has more values (like in a TABLE)
         For Each child In pair
            'not sure how to get other values
         Next
     Else
         'It only has one value
          Debug.Print(pair.Name)
          Debug.Print(pair.Value.ToString)
     End If
  Next
Next
```

The json value for msg is:

```
{
  "content": {
    "@type": "application/xml",
    "F_Form1": {
      "@uid": "fb1ad4ec",
      "F_TableOtherFamily": {
        "F_Table": {
          "F_OtherFamilyName": "BLANK1",
          "F_OtherFamilyID": "BLANK2",
          "F_OtherFamilyRelation": "BLANK3"
        }
      },
      "F_ReceivedYorN": "Y",
      "F_ContractNumber": "901841586"     
    }
  },
  "link": [
    {
      "@href": "../../../../../secure/org/data/c76df8888ada/F_Form1/fb1ad4ec",
      "@rel": "edit"
    }
  ]
}
```

The value for **child** is:

```
{
  "F_Table": {
    "F_OtherFamilyName": "BLANK1",
    "F_OtherFamilyID": "BLANK2",
    "F_OtherFamilyRelation": "BLANK3"
  },
  "F_Table": {
    "F_OtherFamilyName": "BLANK1-1",
    "F_OtherFamilyID": "BLANK2-2",
    "F_OtherFamilyRelation": "BLANK3-3"
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to go about looping to get the values inside **F_Table**??

Answer (score 0):

a Json reader (like the one from newtonsoft) should solve your problem

Take a look at this

[How to read JSON http post response using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979742/how-to-read-json-http-post-response-using-vb)