# Get each key value out of a dictionary of strings object without using newsoft json

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an indexpage.aspx which I post data into on page load. In this page I created list of strings

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim openWith As New SortedList(Of String, String)

    ' Add some elements to the list. There are no 
    ' duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
    openWith.Add("version", "1")
    openWith.Add("key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("publickey"))
    openWith.Add("cmd", "get_callback_address")
    openWith.Add("currency", "coin")
    Call POSTAPI("get_callback_address", openWith)
End Sub
```

Now I have a payment class which has postapi function, here's the class

```
     Public Shared Function POSTAPI(cmd As String, Optional parms As SortedList(Of String, String) = Nothing) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        Dim post_data As String = ""
        For Each parm As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In parms
            If post_data.Length > 0 Then
                post_data += "&"
            End If
            post_data += parm.Key + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(parm.Value)
        Next

        Dim keyBytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(s_privkey)
        Dim postBytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(post_data)
        Dim hmacsha512 = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(keyBytes)
        Dim hmac As String = BitConverter.ToString(hmacsha512.ComputeHash(postBytes)).Replace("-", String.Empty)

        ' do the post:
        Dim cl As New System.Net.WebClient()
        cl.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        cl.Headers.Add("HMAC", hmac)
        cl.Encoding = encoding

        Dim ret = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        Try
            Dim resp As String = cl.UploadString("https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php", post_data)
            Dim decoder = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            ret = decoder.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(resp)
        Catch e As System.Net.WebException
            ret("error") = "Exception while contacting CoinPayments.net: " + e.Message
        Catch e As Exception
            ret("error") = "Unknown exception: " + e.Message
        End Try

        Return ret



    End Function
```

Its posting successfully but A successful call to the 'get_callback_address' or 'get_deposit_address' command will give you a result similar to this (JSON):

```
   {  
         "error":"ok",
         "result":{  
         "address":"1BitcoinAddress",
        "pubkey":"",
        "dest_tag":100,
         }
       }
```

Above are the keys and values is returning. Now my question is I only want to get the values of result and split it so it gives me "`1BitcoinAddress`", "`pubkey`" and save it to my database(I want to get the 3 values of that resultkey so i can save it in my database".

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read JSON http post response using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979742/how-to-read-json-http-post-response-using-vb)

Comment: Why do you need to split it? It's again a dictionary, can you not cast the value of `ret("result")` to a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` ?

Comment: i should cast it into another dictionary value of ret.item("result")?. ok what if i want to do that how do i get the 3 values out from the dictionary and save to db

Comment: If you can't help just let me know rather than insulting me indirectly. have tried several methods but couldn't get the main value i want. its returning both the "result" key and "error" key. I will fully appreciate if you can help not asking me back my questions. thank you

Comment: @james thorpe. the output is different. all i want is just to get the values of key "result" and put them in a string variable

Comment: The output may be different, but the problem and general solution are the same.  Learn the general solution now, rather than something that only works for your specific data, and it'll stand you in good stead for dealing with this issue the _next_ time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you deserialized the incoming json as a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) should have already created a second dictionary for the value of the `result` key. The only thing you have to do now, is create a variable that takes the value stored in the dictionary and cast it as a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` in order to use it, like in this example

```
Dim json As String = "{" +
"""error"":""ok""," +
  """result"":{" +
  """address"":""1BitcoinAddress""," +
  """pubkey"":""""," +
  """dest_tag"":100" +
  "}" +
     "}"
Dim deserializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

'get the full dictionary
Dim dictionary = deserializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(json)

' make sure there is a key in your dictionary
If dictionary.ContainsKey("result") Then
    'cast the value for "result" as a dictionary
    Dim resultDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = _
        DirectCast(dictionary("result"), Dictionary(Of String, Object))

    'you can then access the keys by their key
    Console.WriteLine("address: {0}, pubkey: {1}, dest_tag: {2}", _
        resultDictionary("address"), _
        resultDictionary("pubkey"), _
        resultDictionary("dest_tag"))
End If
```

With your input, the program gives an output on the console, like this:

> address: 1BitcoinAddress, pubkey: , dest_tag: 100

The big question of your question is really why you want to solve the deserialization without the use of [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). On the website for the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx),
 it says at once:

> ***Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization***. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.

Comment: Thank you for your code, have tried it but only returns just the address, pubkey and dest_tag values are now address....im still on it anyway trying to see if i can work it out.

Comment: Have also tried using newtonsft.json it returns error Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type

Comment: @Dannywilliams Wasn't this what you wanted? I have used the json you have provided, and as you can see in the sample it is working, I am unsure what you mean with your first comment. For the second comment, JObject is just a fancy form of a dictionary/dynamic, you can also access any object through the keys