# VB.net 2005 Convert JSON Object to Array List

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net, visual-studio-2005

I have problem to get "kode" from "list" as array from this object.

```
{
           "metaData":{
              "code":"200",
              "message":"Sukses"
           },
           "response":{
              "list":[
                 {
                    "kode":"31486",
                    "nama":"Satro Jadhit, dr"
                 },
                 {
                    "kode":"31492",
                    "nama":"Satroni Lawa, dr"
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
```

i can get anything except array from JSON.
i've tried to use this solution 
 [[How to read JSON http post response using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979742/how-to-read-json-http-post-response-using-vb][1])

and other solution too but my vb don't have some feature from newtonsoft json.
I use visual studio 2005, .net framework 2.0

So, how I get it as my array.

> Edit

this is what i've tried, and I can get value from the "list"
(i use another code, so this value it's different)

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim kodeDpjp as string

Dim json As String = responseFromServer
Dim serObj As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = 
         Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
Dim token As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = serObj.SelectToken("response") 
         ("list")
If (token.GetType() Is GetType(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)) Then
    Console.WriteLine(token)
End If
```

and this is the result

```html
[
  {
    "kode": "8784",
    "nama": "drg.MELANI SARI TANJUNG"
  },
  {
    "kode": "8848",
    "nama": "drg.ARIEF KURNIAWAN"
  },
  {
    "kode": "8873",
    "nama": "drg.SRI ARIANI SUGIARTI"
  }
]
```

i just want "kode" for my array in combobox

Thank you

Comment: *i've tried to use this solution...*  in that case, please [edit] your question to share what you tried that did not work.  For why, see [ask] which suggests ***Help others reproduce the problem***.

Comment: @BrianRogers i use json.net .net 2.0

Comment: @dbc thank you, i've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the result of `serObj.SelectToken("response")("list")` is a `JArray`, you can cast it using `CType` and then use a `For Each` loop to iterate over the items.  Each item here is a `JObject` and you can use the indexer method to get the property values.  Then you can use `CType` again to convert those values to strings.

Here it is in code:

```
' Parse the JSON to a JObject
Dim serObj As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

' Retrieve the list and cast it to a JArray
Dim list As JArray = CType(serObj.SelectToken("response")("list"), JArray)

' Loop over the items in the array (each is a JObject)
For Each item As JObject In list

    ' Get the "kode" property from the JObject and convert it to a string
    Dim kode As String = CType(item("kode"), String)

    ' Get the "nama" property from the JObject and convert it to a string
    Dim nama As String = CType(item("nama"), String)

    ' You can add kode and/or nama to your ComboBox here
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lkrWa4