# De-serializing JSON data in vb

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I have been trying to deserialize JSON data, and this is how far I have gotten before searching StackOverflow and I followed an article however it still broke. I'm getting a runtime error on this line:

```
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
```

Stating "Can not convert Object to String."
Thanks in advance :D

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Structure JSONList
    Dim URL, Name As String 
End Structure

Public Class Form1
    Dim JSONList As List(Of ListViewItem)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn.json")
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer)

        Dim json As String = responseFromServer
        Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
        Dim output As String = ""
        Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)

        Dim JSONDecode() As JSONList = (From j In jsonObject
                                         Select New JSONList() With {.URL = j("URL"),
                                                                     .Name = j("Name")}
                                       ).ToArray()

        MessageBox.Show(JSONDecode(0).Name)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? Please edit your question and add it there (instead of putting int the comments). Also, is it a compiler error (one you see in Visual Studio) or an runtime error (one you get when running the program)?

Comment: For what it is worth - unless you are writing both sides of the JSON/XML conversation I wouldn't expect it to hold up over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net JSON Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize)