# How to deserialize the json string from JAVA to VB.NET?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I am going to implement a VB program to consume the JSON String which is generated by JAVA 
API "net.sf.json" with the following example code,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
...
jsonArray.toString();
```

The above code will generate the JSON string like this

> "[{\"ID\":57,\"ORDER_ID\":130528,\"ITEMS\":[{\"REC_ID\":134484,\"QUANTITY\":1,\"PRINT_FORMAT\":\"A4\",\"PAGE_FROM\":0,\"PAGE_TO\":0},
>       {\"REC_ID\":134485,\"QUANTITY\":1,\"PRINT_FORMAT\":\"A4\",\"PAGE_FROM\":0,\"PAGE_TO\":0},
>       {\"REC_ID\":134486,\"QUANTITY\":1,\"PRINT_FORMAT\":\"A4\",\"PAGE_FROM\":0,\"PAGE_TO\":0},
>       {\"REC_ID\":134487,\"QUANTITY\":1,\"PRINT_FORMAT\":\"A4\",\"PAGE_FROM\":0,\"PAGE_TO\":0}]}]"

How can I consume this JSON using VB.NET

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize This might help

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try. By the way, my JSON string seems with invalid characters like \"

Comment: I dont know where you are getting the json from but it looks like its doing some escaping of the "  try and do a replace on \" to remove the \ before you run the deserialize.