# How to Format JSON output from web service asmx to use with Google visualization

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, google-visualization, asmx

I have a .asmx webservice that outputs a JSON string like this:

```
"d":"{\"cols\": [{\"type\": \"datetime\" ,\"id\": \"EvenDate\" ,\"label\": \"EvenDate\" }, {\"type\": \"number\" ,\"id\": \"Entries\" ,\"label\": \"Entries\" }], \"rows\" : [{\"c\" : [{\"v\": \"Date(2014, 5, 16, 0, 0, 0)\"}, {\"v\": 1}]}, {\"c\" : [{\"v\": \"Date(2014, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0)\"}, {\"v\": 1}]}, {\"c\" : [{\"v\": \"Date(2014, 5, 23, 0, 0, 0)\"}, {\"v\": 5}]}]}"}
```

Google Visualization requires the data to be like this.

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

My JSON output is good except that the webservice is adding the `d:` and also the `\` but I think the `\` are just escape characters. Is there a way to remove the `d:` from the JSON response?

This is my webservice:

```
' google datatable json wrapper
Imports Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper
...
Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable
dt = tlsession.FillSessionTable(sqlstr)
Dim dataTable = SystemDataTableConverter.Convert(dt)
Dim jsonString As String = dataTable.GetJson()
Return jsonString
```

Can you please point me to the right direction on how I could fix the JSON ouput? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize

Comment: I doubt very much that your JSON string actually includes the backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to get a Google DataTable directly from a .net web services is with the [Google DataTable .Net Wrapper](http://googledatatablelib.codeplex.com/).  Their documentation is clearly written so I won't get into too much detail with examples here.  I will say that you can use the library to convert a System.Data.DataTable into an excellent JSON representation of a Google DataTable, and it even properly serializes DateTime objects into the more unusual format used by the Google Visualization API.

Edit: Also, they have a NuGet package [here](https://nuget.org/packages/Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper).

Comment: Thank you. While I was trying to do with asmx and ajax, this solved my problem.

Comment: I haven't personally used ASP.Net Web Services, but it's still ASP.Net, so I imagine you should be able to send any response you want, as long as you know how.  So you could still use an AJAX call to get the JSON returned by this library.  I'm doing the same with ASP.Net Web API.