# How to match the particular part from the nth index of the specific character?

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I have the input data as,

```
 "Thumbnail":"/images/7.0.2.5076_1/spacer.gif","URL":"http://id800/home/LayoutManager/l1.html/1407462681_292_2_2_1398567201/"
```

And I want to match the `l1.html` part of it. It can be anything. So I want to match the Part of `URL` which occurs before the second last occurrence of the `/` and after the third last occurrence of the `/`. That part either the number, alphanumeric, or the alphnumeric with `.html` extension. so besically I want to match the part between the 3rd and 2nd `/` from end. I tried lots of combinations but I was unable to come up with. Any help would be great.

Comment: This looks like JSON object, get the value from JSON using the key `URL`, split by `/` and get the second last value from array.

Comment: I am getting this as string value in code behind. I can not use the external library for this.

Comment: Regex `\"URL\"\:\"http[s]?\:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/`

Comment: @MayurKoshti this will match `"URL":"http://id800/home/LayoutManager/l1.html` this whole part

Comment: Have you tried anything (+ have a specific programming doubt and want to learn and grow as a programmer) or you are just expecting someone to work for free for you?

Comment: @varocarbas I tried lots of combinations for last 3-4 hours but was unable to come up with anything that is helpfull. And all the combinations I tried was wrong so didn't included in question.

Comment: @CoderofCode You know what action would avoid comments like the one I wrote above + downvotes + being voted to be put on hold + getting an answer as quickly as possible? Just write what you tried; your best shot. It might be wrong (you are here for something). Making mistakes is not a problem at all; although some people might not like not seeing some kind of effort/knowledge.

Comment: Here is a [JSON deserialization example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize).

Answer (score 1):

**Pattern:**

```
\".+?(\w+\.\w{3,5})\/.+?\"
```

- `\"` will match starting and ending quote
- `.+?` will match any number of characters
- `\w+` will match any number of words
- `\.` will match .(dot)
- `\w{3,5}` will match any word which are 3-5 characters long
- `\/` will match /(forward slash)
- `()` these parenthesis capture in separate group

**Code in action:**

```
string pattern = "\".+?(\\w+\\.\\w{3,5})\\/.+?\"";
string text = "\"Thumbnail\":\"/images/7.0.2.5076_1/spacer.gif\",\"URL\":\"http://id800/home/LayoutManager/l1.html/1407462681_292_2_2_1398567201/\"";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
if (matches != null && matches[0].Groups != null)
{
    string value = matches[0].Groups[1].Value; //Output: l1.html
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the whole JSON string, but I think my snippet will help you get what you want anyway ***without regex***. Add a reference to *System.Web.Extensions*, and use the following code:

```
Dim s As String = "[{""Thumbnail"":""/images/7.0.2.5076_1/spacer.gif"",""URL"":""http://id800/home/LayoutManager/l1.html/1407462681_292_2_2_1398567201/""}]" ' "[{""application_id"":""1"",""application_package"":""abc""},{""application_id"":""2"",""application_package"":""xyz""}]"
Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(s)
For Each d In dict
    For Each v In d
       If v.Key = "URL" Then
           Dim tmp = v.Value.Trim("/"c).ToString().Split("/"c)
           MsgBox(tmp(tmp.Length - 2))
       End If
    Next
Next
```

Result:

[image]

The substring you need can be obtained without a regex by mere splitting the value with `/`, and accessing the last but one element.