# VB.NET Loop Through XML Results

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have redone this question as a few have suggested that it is difficult to understand what I am after so have cut down the question somewhat.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <succesfulResponses>
        <position>0</position>
        <response>
            <dln>BBUTU204250VS9VT</dln>
            <licence>
                <entitlements>
                    <code>A</code>
                    <validFrom/>
                    <validTo/>
                    <priorTo>false</priorTo>
                    <type>F</type>
                </entitlements>
                <entitlements>
                    <code>B</code>
                    <validFrom/>
                    <validTo/>
                    <priorTo>false</priorTo>
                    <type>F</type>
                </entitlements>
            </licence>
        </response>
    </succesfulResponses>
    <succesfulResponses>
        <position>1</position>
        <response>
            <dln>BTXRS755313Y99AT</dln>
            <licence>           
                <entitlements>
                    <code>A</code>
                    <validFrom>2003-02-28</validFrom>
                    <validTo>2043-05-30</validTo>
                    <priorTo>false</priorTo>
                    <type>P</type>
                </entitlements>
                <entitlements>
                    <code>AM</code>
                    <validFrom>2014-05-14</validFrom>
                    <validTo>2043-05-30</validTo>
                    <priorTo>false</priorTo>
                    <type>P</type>
                </entitlements>
            </licence>
            <httpStatusCode>200</httpStatusCode>
        </response>
    </succesfulResponses>
</root>
```

This is the XML I have returned, I submit several ID's to the service and it returns this XML.

If I send 2 ID's it returns 2 'successfulResponses' elements for each ID these ID's you can see in the child node 'dln' beneath 'response', you can see they are different.

'position' is simply which ID i submitted in the 'request' first. 'response' also has an element called 'licence' and several 'entitlement' elements.

I wish to insert these 'entitlements' into a datatable that is formatted in this way

```
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Code", GetType(String)))
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Valid From", GetType(String)))
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Valid To", GetType(String)))
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Prior To", GetType(String)))
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Type", GetType(String)))
    Results.EntitlementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Driver", GetType(String)))
```

Each column relates to an node beneath each 'entitlements' element. I wish to add a new row to my datatable everytime I have an 'entitlements' element.

There is an additional column 'Driver', this needs to be populated with the number in 'position'.

So my the output to my table I would like to have the following:

[image]
As you can see the 'Driver' Column relates to the value of the 'position' node.

I hope this makes more sense than my previous. I have removed any of my own code I have stated I have done as its clearly not what was required.

Comment: Did you consider deserializing your JSON to .net objects instead? Seems like a lot of overhead to transform to Xml and query that.

Comment: @Filburt I wouldn't really have any idea where to begin there I'm afraid - I'm very much self taught in what I know, so its all a learning curve for me.

Comment: Check out [VB.net JSON Deserialize](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8118019/205233) - it should get you started.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks for that, I ideally would get around to figuring that out when I have more time. I just need to get this data into the tables at the moment.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what output you're trying to achieve here  -could you add expected output from your XML doc?  You're taking only the last `dln`, but using positions from all drivers, what entitlements do you want and where do you want them?

Comment: @DanField please see my update above

Comment: Is your GUI an HTML web page? Because XML can be transformed easily into HTML using XSLT. And as @DanField suggests please visually show your expected output. Your written description is not too clear. Help us help you.

Comment: @Parfait It is not it is a windows form, I will try and do something visually because I am actually find it difficult to explain, I am going to redo the question with some cut down XML and Code, that I have done just for the benefit of this question.

Comment: @Parfait please see above

Comment: @DanField please see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd heartily second the recommendation to deserialize the JSON directly to a CLR Object, and you might also find it easier to use the `XDocument` API, but if you really have to use the `XmlDocument` model for some reason, this code should help

```
Dim DriverNo As String

Using nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/succesfulResponses")
    For Each node In nodes 
        Dim DLN As String = ""
        DriverNo = node.SelectSingleNode("position").InnerText
        DLN = node.SelectSingleNode("response/dln").InnerText.ToString()

        Using entitlements As XmlNodeList = node.SelectNodes("response/licence/entitlements")
            For Each entitlement In entitlements
                Dim code, validFrom, validTo, priorTo, type As String
                code = entitlement.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText
                validFrom = entitlement.SelectSingleNode("validFrom").InnerText
                validTo = entitlement.SelectSingleNode("validTo").InnerText
                priorTo = entitlement.SelectSingleNode("priorTo").InnerText
                type = entitlement.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText
                ' do what you need to with the variables here
            Next

        End Using

    Next
End Using
```

This way, you're iterating through each `successfulResponses` node, grabbing the DLN and the DriverNo, and then iterating through each `entitlements` node and getting the data from there.  That will result in one row per entitlement.

The `do what you need to with the variables here` will be your actual code to insert into your datatable or whatever you're using.

Comment: Hi Dan,

Top man that has sorted out what I needed, I will by all means look into JSON to a CLR Object but that is a new learning curve and something I don't have time for right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml Linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("succesfulResponses").Select(Function(x) New With { _
           .position = CType(x.Element("position"), Integer), _
           .entitlements = x.Descendants("entitlements").Select(Function(y) New With { _
                               .code = CType(y.Element("code"), String), _
                               .validFrom = y.Elements("validFrom").Where(Function(z) z.Value.Length > 0).Select(Function(a) CType(a, DateTime)).FirstOrDefault(), _
                               .validTo = y.Elements("validTo").Where(Function(z) z.Value.Length > 0).Select(Function(a) CType(a, DateTime)).FirstOrDefault(), _
                               .priorTo = y.Elements("priorTo").Where(Function(z) z.Value.Length > 0).Select(Function(a) CType(a, Boolean)).FirstOrDefault(), _
                               .type = y.Elements("type").Where(Function(z) z.Value.Length > 0).Select(Function(a) CType(a, String)).FirstOrDefault() _
                               }).ToList() _
        }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: A debugging nightmare.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code.  It is used all the time especially in c#.  The code works so what is there to debug?