# How to read json return string?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Having trouble to read `json` return in a useful way

Searching "all over" to find how to create classes and how to de-serialize json return

This is the json return:

```
[[{"metadata":{},"contentType":0,"contentId":0,"objectName":"Mi","objectId":"1","classId":"118"},
{"metadata":{},"contentType":0,"contentId":0,"objectName":"BA","objectId":"224445","classId":"103"},
{"metadata":{},"contentType":0,"contentId":0,"objectName":"1","objectId":"239011","classId":"104"},
{"metadata":{},"contentType":0,"contentId":0,"objectName":"1","objectId":"239309","classId":"105"}]]
```

Tried Visual Studio (VB.net) Paste Special to create json classes, but I can't seem to get my head around how to use it. Using Newtonsoft.Json.

These are the classes, how do I deserialize json and make it useful?

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property Property1()() As Class1
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Public Property metadata As Metadata
    Public Property contentType As Integer
    Public Property contentId As Integer
    Public Property objectName As String
    Public Property objectId As String
    Public Property classId As String
End Class

Public Class Metadata
End Class
```

Comment: Seems posting does not consider my line breaks when pasting...

Comment: Dvyn Resh fixed it for you. To get the line breaks verbatim, you need to use code blocks, either with three back ticks on the line before and the line after the code, or by selecting the code block with the mouse and clicking the `{}` icon.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net JSON Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize)

Comment: The linked question is based on .NET built-ins, if you want to use NewtonSoft's offering, you would be doing something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonstring)`.

Comment: And in future don't tag 'json.net' when you specify 'Newtonsoft.Json', they are two different things.

Comment: @video.baba Newtonsoft.Json and Json.Net are indeed the same thing.  If you go to the [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com) website you will see the product is actually called Json.Net.

Comment: @Brian Rogers, hmmm, interesting. I'm sure not long ago they were two different things. I can remember going to the JSON.NET website, which now seem to have gone, was there a 'buy-out'? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @video.baba AFAIK Json.Net has always been a Newtonsoft product, created by [James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/bio) around 2005 and first released in 2006, according to their [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).  I can't speak to the ownership of the json.net domain, however.

Comment: @Brian Rogers Hey I've probably got my wires-crossed, it happens at least once a night hehe. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array of arrays of `Class1` objects, so you need to deserialize to that.

```
Dim data As Class1()() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Class1()())(json)
```

You don't actually need the `Rootobject` class here.

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1JuaYk